# ts file is not showing the node module import path .it says couldn't find the declaration for "../node_modules/pdfmake/build/pdfmake";

Tags: asp.net, typescript, asp.net-core, import, node-modules

here i am using dotnet core project to implement ts file and inside
ts file it says unable to find the module pdfmake .

~

```
import is unable to find the path of module where i have already 
installed that module 
in axcatly same path

import * as pdfMake from "../node_modules/pdfmake/build/pdfmake";
//<reference path="../node_modules/pdfmake/build/pdfmake" />
import * as pdfFonts from 
"../node_modules/pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts";
pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;

~
```

Comment: Can you tell me  the position of  your node_modules in the project?[You can find the answer here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.